# Using regex_iterator to go through the tags of an HTML file

Tags: html, c++, regex

I'm writing a web browser and trying to use regex_iterator to go through the tags of an HTML document and ultimately create a document tree. First I need a regular expression that will get me an HTML tag. The following should print out each HTML tag

```
#include <string>
#include <regex>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{

    std::string s("<!DOCTYPE html><head></head><body><div class='container' id='someId'><p>Here's a p tag</p><p>Here's another p tag</p></div></body>");
    std::regex e("[someRegularExpression]");
    std::regex_iterator<std::string::iterator> htmlTagRover ( s.begin(), s.end(), e );
    std::regex_iterator<std::string::iterator> offend;
    while (htmlTagRover != offend)
        std::cout << htmlTagRover->str() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

if `[someRegularExpression]` is equal to a regular expression for an HTML tag. Bur I'm getting the following error when I try to run the program:

**/home/svzQOJ/ccEMKoqM.o: In function `main':
prog.cpp:(.text.startup+0xd1): undefined reference to`std::regex_iterator<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator, char, std::regex_traits >::regex_iterator(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator, __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator, std::basic_regex > const&, std::bitset<11u>)'
prog.cpp:(.text.startup+0xdc): undefined reference to `std::regex_iterator<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char*, std::string>, char, std::regex_traits<char> >::regex_iterator()'
prog.cpp:(.text.startup+0x1af): undefined reference to`std::regex_iterator<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator, char, std::regex_traits >::operator!=(std::regex_iterator<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator, char, std::regex_traits > const&)'
prog.cpp:(.text.startup+0x1be): undefined reference to `std::regex_iterator<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator, char, std::regex_traits >::operator->()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status**

Any idea why?

Comment: [Relevant](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Answer (score 0):

According to [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/regex_iterator), you don't need the `<std::string::iterator>` in your calls and you need to use the std::sregex_iterator (notice the s) to use regex with std::string.